# Datastax Cassandra installation on windows 7

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I was using Datastax 3.4 64 bit (java 8 64 bit) on Windows 7 for a while, suddenly the Datastax service on windows was not starting up at all. When I click start in the windows-services page, it starts for like 10 seconds and stop automatically. I then uninstalled Datastax from windows program-uninstall page. Then again I installed Datastax, but this time I'm not able to see the Datastax service at all in the services page. I tried to start the cassandra in foreground and it give following error.

```
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup script

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
for performance and stability reasons.


*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
Performance of this node will suffer.
Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.


*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin>Error: Could not find or load
 main class Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\.logs.gc.log
```

I'm clueless how to start the Datastax/cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cassandra Installation Process in window 7,8,10.

- Step-1
- You must have Datastax community edition Center(Dev Center
     Software).
- You can downloaded latest version Cassandra from
     Apache official website
- http://like...http://cassandra.apache.org/down...
- JDK must be required.
- Windows platform is required.
- Step-2
- Normal way to Installation this Software like Datastax
     community edition  Center.
- Complete Installation then go to
     windows start programs.
- Search Cassandra CQL Shell and run the
     Cassandra Shell.
- After running Cassandra shell.
- you will see the following command line
- Step-3
- You can create a keyspace,Tables and write queries.
- Step-4
- Cassandra installation step by step process will be Done.